# Outputting a patched DLL from x64dbg

Tags: dll, patching, x64dbg

I've been working on reversing an extremely outdated piece of software that I happen to need in order to get at the information stored in some equally outdated "database" files.

Using x64dbg, I've patched out the validity checks for the serial / request / activation strings, and the software does successfully go through it's activation routine.

The problem is that I now need to export the correctly patched DLL in order for the software to work, but x64dbg will only "apply" 3/20 of the necessary patches. It will, however, export a .1337 patch file that contains all 20.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: any error messages?

Comment: No errors, per se, other than it says "3/20 patches applied" instead of "20/20"

Comment: Biswapriyo: I don't have / use IDA. I can get it, I'm sure, but I don't know how to use it to re-create my work from x64dbg. Any advice on making the .1337 patch work with IDA?

Comment: @MarkSchlachter: maybe check if the file on disk has been patched already in the other 17 locations

Comment: What is the solution for patching at the end of a section? I'm trying to create a code cave but I can't patch the file because of this issue...

Answer (score 3):

You get the “x/y patches applied” message when you try to patch at a virtual address that has no file offset associated with it.

Generally this happens if you add code at the end of a section. In rare cases it could be that there is a bug in converting the virtual addresses to file offsets. If you think that is the case, provide the relevant binary and patch location and open an issue at http://issues.x64dbg.com